# scroll bar for long list of buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a problem desinging a window using PySide.

```
class MainForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__()
        # init window

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea(self)

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)

        self.leftspltr = QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.rightspltr = QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        self.scroll.setWidget(self.leftspltr)
        self.rightspltr.addWidget(self.table)         

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.leftspltr)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.rightspltr)


        self.setWindowTitle("...")

        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.move(11,220)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Key","Full","HR"])

        dic = dumpered_hash.dict_naming_values
        os.popen("rm dumpered_hash dumpered_hash.py dumpered_hash.pyc")

        xpos = 0
        ypos = 0
        for key, val1 in sorted(dic.iteritems()):
            btn = QPushButton(key, self)
            btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.fillTbl, val1, len(val1) + 1))
            btn.setFixedSize(84,20)
            self.leftspltr.addWidget(btn)
```

i`m trying to design a window that has some button (more than 30) placed virtically, so I want to have them in scroll bar that fits the window size, and a table at the right side that doesn`t move while scrolling.
the code above gives me a tiny scroll bar that moves the button, bur they are out of the window size.

what wrong there ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do here. However, you are placing your buttons in a vertical splitter and then fixing their size. Instead, place the buttons in a vertical layout, and then place that and the table widget into a horizontal splitter.

```
class MainForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__()
        # init window

        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.btnbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)

        self.spltr = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

        self.setWindowTitle("...")

        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.move(11,220)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Key","Full","HR"])

        dic = {}
        for i in range(30):
            dic['foo '+str(i)] = [i]

        for key, val1 in sorted(dic.iteritems()):
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton(key, self)
            self.btnbox.addWidget(btn)

        # must place layout into a widget before adding to QScrollArea
        holder = QtGui.QWidget()
        holder.setLayout(self.btnbox)
        self.scroll.setWidget(holder)  
        self.spltr.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.spltr.addWidget(self.table)         

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.spltr)
```

I would also like to note, that is it better to include the simplest piece of code necessary to reproduce your problem. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with the lines containing `dumpered_hash`, but it seems to be irrelevant, as well as a dubious use of a deprecated function, and makes it impossible to run your code without modification.  Make it easier for people to help you!